# Crashing my browser with while loop, PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to help create a table for a web page and can't seem to spot where this while loop is crashing the browser.

```
  <?php
    $counter1 = 1;


    $weekDay = date('l');
    echo "Today is $weekDay " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br/>";
    echo "<h1>Table Construction</h1>";
    echo "<table><tr>";
    $dateNow = date("Y/m/d");
    $dayStore = array();
    while ($counter1 < 8) {
        $stringCheck = "+" . $counter1 . " day";
        $dateMod = strtotime($stringCheck, strtotime($dateNow));
        $weekDay = date ('D',$dateMod);
        echo "<td id=\"bolder\">" . date ('l',$dateMod) . " " . date("Y/m/d", $dateMod). "</td>";
        $dayStore[$counter1]=$weekDay;
        $counter1++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";//"<tr>";
    $counter1=1;
    while ($counter1<8){
        echo "<td><form name=\"timeslots\">";
        $dayVar = $dayStore[$counter1];
        echo $dayVar. " ";
        $counterHours = 0;
        if ($dayVar == "Mon"||$dayVar == "Tue"||$dayVar ==  "Wed"||$dayVar ==  "Thu"||$dayVar == "Fri") {
            $startTime = 9;
            $counterHours = 0;
            while ($counterHours<3) {
                $timeString = $startTime . ":00 am";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input><br/>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
            while (startTime<12 && $counterHours>=3) {
                $timeString = ($startTime-12) . ":00 pm";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
        }
        else if ($dayVar == "Sat") {
            $startTime = 9;
            $counterHours = 0;
            while ($counterHours<3) {
                $timeString = $startTime . ":00 am";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
            while ($counterHours<12 && $counterHours>=3) {
                $timeString = ($startTime-12) . ":00 pm";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
        }   
        else if ($dayVar == "Sun") {
            $startTime = 11;
            $counterHours = 0;
            while ($counterHours<3) {
                $timeString = $startTime . ":00 am";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
            while ($counterHours<12 && $counterHours>=3) {
                $timeString = ($startTime-12) . ":00 pm";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$dayStore[$counter1]\" value=\"$startTime\">$timeString</input>";
                $startTime = $startTime+1;
                $counterHours++;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "displaying a proper message";
        }
        echo "</form></td>";
        $counter1++;
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
    ?>
```

When I upload this inside my main page to my school's server and run it, nothing loads and the browser crashes. With the variable ranges I've selected, I don't think it should be doing that...

Comment: Do you get any errors? (1. Where is your constant `startTime` defined? 100 bucks on it, that you don't have this constant defined and you want to use your variable which that name)

Comment: I get error saying `undefined constant startTime` Please define it

Comment: Does anyone else feel uneasy when they see "Run code snippet" with a title that includes "Crashing my browser"?  ;)

Comment: Yep, it was an old variable I stopped using. Careless mistake and I feel bad for wasting your time with a proofreading problem, thank you very much.

Comment: @RickSmith haha. good one :). I just now edited it :) It was mentioned as HTML and JS code snippet before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos:

```
    while (startTime<12 && $counterHours>=3) {
           ^^^^^^^^^ missing $
```

undefined constant, therefore being evaluated to `0`, making the expression

```
    while (0 < 12 && $counterHours>=3) {
    while (true && true) {
    while (true) {
```

and therefore an infinite loop.

If you were running with debug options enabled (e.g. `display_errors` and `error_reporting`), you'd have been told about the undefined constant. These settings should **NEVER** be off on a devel/debug system.

Comment: Do I get my 100$ now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583617/crashing-my-browser-with-while-loop-php#comment49237036_30583617 :)?

Comment: Maybe worth to say, that the constant is just converted into a string with the name itself, but since it is in a numerical context it gets converted to a number, which here is 0

Comment: Thanks very much, I think this is just a result of staring at a screen for too long.